# What can I use at the top of my stairs for a winch mount?

Tags: winch

I need to get a heavy concrete grinder (180 lbs), with wheels, down my stairs. I was thinking of getting a winch, but i have nothing to mount it to (the opposing wall is too far away). I was thinking of making a bracket for the top of the stairs, or perhaps even a table (where the winch could be mounted under the table where the 4 legs would be up against the wall) or perhaps some scaffold.
There are many out-of-the box thinkers on their group, so looking for some ideas.

Comment: $40 - $20 to each of 2 guys outside your local Home Depot - will take care of it quickly. Or similar - the specifics may vary regionally, but there are always people available for quick "move stuff around" jobs.

Comment: Show us the top of your stairs.

Comment: Earlier this week with three helpers we moved a commercial grade treadmill into my basement, that weighs 400 lbs, using just muscle. Your 180 pound grinder should be no problem with you + two other people.

Comment: You can cheaply hire movers from the uhaul website, the "legit" version of home-depot pickups.

Comment: if the wall is too far use a longer rope.

Comment: if it's rented ask them to collect it and they can lift it off your balcony with their Hiab.

Comment: I think that all the comments and answers boil down to "don't mount a winch". 180 lbs isn't _that_ heavy, but the mounting necessary for a winch requires far more thinking and engineering that a little bit of borrowed or rented muscle. I do wonder how you got it _up_ the stairs in the first place...

Comment: @Freeman We are renting the grinder. It needs to go down into the basement. Then I need to get it up afterwards. I’ve fond two young guys to help me, so I think I’m OK. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having recently moved a refrigerator of about that weight up a set of stairs using only a hand-truck (for wheels) it can be done (I'm not abnormally strong or huge.) Literally take it one step at a time.

If the wheels are not of adequate size to roll on the steps, use a hand-truck with large enough wheels (but not so large you can't stop on a step) and ignore the wheels on the grinder.

But it can be more easily done with two or more people, whether rolling or (when your people can lift it and not be at their limits and at risk of dropping it) brute-force carrying.

Comment: Don't use a "hand truck" use an appliance dolly, such as [this one](http://appliancedollyinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Harper-Trucks-6781-193x300.jpg). They are available for rent from moving rental companies and have "climbers" that are designed to gently roll heaving items down the steps instead of dropping the wheels down the step.

Answer (score 3):

**Take it apart?**

I dont know what exactly you have.  But maybe you could take it apart and move it is manageable pieces.  The grinding wheel comes out for sure because those must be replaced.  Possibly the thing even has weights because weighting it helps the grinding action.  If you could reduce it to pieces it would be easier to get it down the stairs then assemble it again.

Comment: A valid approach to many heavy things, though in this case I wonder if it's a rental tool, which might mean anything more than the grinding wheels might require approval from the rental agency or risk a large financial penalty.)

Answer (score 0):

rent an electric stair climing hand truck,